# Can't extract float value by XPath: /report/counter[@type='INSTRUCTION']/@missed failed issue in Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, code-coverage

We are trying to enable the gitHub --> Jenkins --> sonar(sonarVersion:Version 7.9.3) Integration.
We are facing the below issue

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Strange Jacoco report!
  File path: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/modules/type/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/jacoco.xml
 Can't extract float value by XPath: /report/counter[@type='INSTRUCTION']/@missed
from:
```

```
at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.JacocoParser.getByXpath(JacocoParser.java:95)
at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.JacocoParser.getCoverage(JacocoParser.java:133)
at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.JacocoParser.get(JacocoParser.java:128)
at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.GetCoverageCallable.getFloats(GetCoverageCallable.java:56)
at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.GetCoverageCallable.invoke(GetCoverageCallable.java:82)
at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.GetCoverageCallable.invoke(GetCoverageCallable.java:35)
at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3086)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)Build step 'Record Master Coverage' marked build as failure
```

Any solution please.